# How to run spring bean on specific thread

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have a a springBoot app that has a few beans that startup and run normally. It also has one `@Service` with a `@KafkaListener` that I need to run off of the main thread.

The KafkaListener is not thread safe and I think it cannot be `@Async`. I don't want to spin off many threads, it can only run on a single thread.

```
        SpringApplication.run(myApp.class, args);
    }
```

```
@Service
public class SubscriberService {
    @KafkaListener(topics = "symbols", groupId = "group_id", topicPartitions = {@TopicPartition(topic = "topicName", partitionOffsets = @PartitionOffset(partition = "#{topicUtil.getPartition()}", initialOffset = "0"))})
    public void getSymbols(String message) throws IOException {
        //do some stuff with each message from kafka
    }
```

What can I do to have spring run this on its own (single) thread off of main?

Comment: And what is not thread safe about this? I don't see shared state.

Comment: The stuff inside `getSymbols`.

Comment: There is no shared state, hence it is thread safe. What happens inside the method is local to the current executing stack and won't leak. Also the listener is async already because it is triggered not from main but a thread that is reading of kafka.